# Gui in C on windows cygwin

Tags: c, gtk, cygwin

I'm trying to make a script that can generate a kind of chat client in cygwin on windows but I don't have a clue how to start, I saw something like gtk+ but how do I get that inside of cygwin, and what have I to do after that?

Comment: You might want to try programming in python, using twisted and pygtk, and you'll be amazed how much faster you get this chat thing you want done.

Comment: There are a variety choices on cross-platform GUI libraries. If you are familiar with C++ and you do not need complex interfaces, personally I recommend FLTK. This library is so small that you can statically link to it with minor increase in file size and memory use. Releasing portable binary executables is very easy. Most of other cross-platform GUI libraries do not have this advantage(although they have their own unique features).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin has an [assortment](http://www.cygwin.com/packages/) of gtk packages.  After that you need to read some documentation and learn how to use the toolkit to make your program.  [Here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/stable/) is a tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Are you locked to Cygwin or are you using that because you think that is where Gtk+ apps can run? In any case I seem to remember those packages as options in the cygwin installer. Also this link seems valid: http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/ . I tend to generate native programs using Gtk+ on MinGW instead so my users don't have to have all of cygwin installed to run my software.